# Getting PHP to process .jnlp files

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to generate Java Web Start files using PHP. Right now I'm just sending a Content-Type header, which works for me, but some users are having problems. I think using the correct file extension would make it work; is there a way to execute PHP code in other file types, or alternatively redirect a .jnlp URL (with query string) to a PHP script?

I tried using various AddType/AddHandler directives in an .htaccess, but none of them have any effect; is there another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Via `mod rewrite` it should work with this code snippet (save as `.htaccess`):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*).jnlp$ $1.php
```

Now when entering `asdf.jnlp` you should be redirected (internally) to `asdf.php` ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to put your AddType/Handler in httpd.conf and nott in .htaccess. Do you have access to the former?

Comment: The site is on a shared hosting account for now, so I do not. Is there a way to use mod_rewrite to do this?